# Connecting to socket with authentication in python

Tags: python, sockets, mongodb, http-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb instance through a python socket. The url looks like this

username:password@host.com:port

how can I connect to this with a python socket?

The following code gives me this error: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

```
import socket
import tornado

full_url = '%s:%s@%s' % (username, password, host)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((full_url, port))
stream = iostream.IOStream(s)
```

EDIT - the reason I ask is because asyncmongo doesn't support this type of url right now. I'm trying to see if I can write a patch. The asyncmongo library connects using a socket like the one in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a driver to connect to mongodb. If you are using Tornado (it looks like you intend to do so), try [asyncmongo](https://github.com/bitly/asyncmongo); if you are using a threaded web server/application framework (Django, Pylons, etc) you can use [PyMongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver) directly.

---

**Edit:** As for why this code doesn't work, the `socket` module doesn't accept URLs for connection, just hostname and port. It is a low-level library. To connect to (web) urls, consider using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).

---

**Edit 2:** Authentication in MongoDB is not handled at the transport level, it's handled at the application level. I suggest you first read [Implementing Authentication in a Driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Implementing+Authentication+in+a+Driver), and then take a look at how PyMongo implements authentication (in [connection.py](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/connection.py#L170) and [database.py](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/database.py#L554)). You'll also need to port or reimplement the MongoDB connection URI parsing for asyncmongo, which is documented [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections).

Comment: i clarified this in the question, but I'm trying to get asyncmongo to work with these urls :)