# Local proxy forwarding all traffic to another proxy using socket

Tags: python, sockets, authentication, proxy

I want to write a localhost proxy that forwards all the traffic to another proxy (something like this https://gist.github.com/darkwave/52842722c0c451807df4). The problem is that remote proxy is authenticated, while using urlib in python I can simply provide user:password@proxy.host.io and all works fine, but it doesn't work on socket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to socket with authentication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540515/connecting-to-socket-with-authentication-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I can see confirmation of what i wrote in referenced ticked:

Edit: As for why this code doesn't work, the socket module doesn't accept URLs for connection, just hostname and port. It is a low-level library. To connect to (web) urls, consider using urllib2 or httplib.

I don't know how to use urlib or httplib since they are too high level.

Comment: Try the [socks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SocksiPy) lib.